# Does anyone know of a Cache component for TIdHTTP?

Tags: delphi, caching, indy

I'm looking for a cache implementation for the Indy IdHTTP component that would be used for checking of a specific resource is already cached before doing the actual GET and returning the cached resource instead (if appropriate)?

If the component would be a derived class from TIdHTTP and handle the cache-features automatically it would be the easiest way for me, so I could just replace my existing IdHTTP objects with the new component.

Has anyone ever seen such a component for D2010?

Comment: I don't know of any for Indy, but ALWininetHttpClient uses IE's cache if you don't "HAVE" to use Indy.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/alcinoe/

Comment: In this case it's rather important to use the Indy components. The use for this will be for a simplified performance testing solution that needs to act like a browser, and Indy offers all other parts except the cache thing...

Comment: I just found that http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphixml-rpc/ has some basic caching in it's code, which uses Indy.

Comment: thanx, will look at it promptly

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a component to do that, but you can implement your own based on response header Cache-Control and Expires-Date (i am not sure if it is the corrent name). You should save the page on a file with the Expires date on it, so you can check if you already have the page on cache before make the request to the server. I guess it is what some proxies do, like Squid (of course not as simple as that).

Check this out: [Caching in HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html)

Comment: OP states s/he is searching for a already-made cache, not for advise on how to made his own cache system.

Comment: I know that. I just said that he/she could do it, since I dont know a component that is able to do that.

Comment: in such a case, I usually post a comment on the question, because I have no answer to post at all!, or maybe do nothing if the question is about 9 months old!!!